# Как выбрать уникальные из массива

Tags: php

Запутался.. Как выбрать уникальные из массива, если у меня одинаковые displayname, но разные email адреса. Суть в том, что если попадается два с одинаковыми displayname, то надо выбрать тот у которого в email есть yandex.ru А если НЕ попадаются одинаковые displayname (одинаковые entries), то вообще ничего не делать, оставить всё как есть и неважно, что там есть в email.

```
  $entries=array();
$entries[0]["displayname"][0]='Alex'; $entries[0]["email"][0]='123@mail.ru';      //первый массив (меня не надо отображть): Имя пользователя, email пользователя
$entries[1]["displayname"][0]='Alex'; $entries[1]["email"][0]='256@yandex.ru';   //второй массив (меня надо оставить): Имя пользователя, email пользователя

$entries[2]["displayname"][0]='Anna'; $entries[2]["email"][0]='456456@mail.ru';       //третй массив (меня не надо отображть): Имя пользователя, email пользователя
$entries[3]["displayname"][0]='Anna'; $entries[3]["email"][0]='778888@yandex.ru';    //четвертый массив (меня надо оставить): Имя пользователя, email пользователя

//.....................

$entries[4]["displayname"][0]='Serg'; $entries[2]["email"][0]='3453549990@bk.ru';       //третй массив (у меня нет двойника, меня надо оставить): Имя пользователя, email пользователя
```

Comment: У Вас либо опечатка, либо Вы делаете что-то очень странное и непонятное: в конце Вы пишете опять `$entries[2]` - ключ именно 2?

Comment: исправил ....................

Comment: И откуда вообще у Вас берется этот массив? Если из базы - то может сразу выбирать в том виде, в котором Вам данные понадобятся, а не этот "массив, вложенный в массив, вложенный в массив", суть которого - просто соответствие имени и емейла.

Comment: в базе AD встречаются и User и Contact с одинаковыми именами (отличаются только email), в таком случае надо отобразить только contact. Фильтр по AD я и так использую само собой. Но выбрать по такому принципу ка кнаписал не знаю. Цикл у меня уже используется вместо ключей - конечно $i

Comment: кстати этот массив многоуровневый - это данные в чистом виде,  считанные из LDAP

Comment: я хотел сократить, там меняются только первый ключ от 0 до ...count. и второй ключ: displayname или email или department... а третий ключ, можно вообще не иметь ввиду (для упрощения) он всегда постоянный - 0.

Answer (score 0):

Вот то, что Вы хотите - массив в котором ключ - имя, значение - емейл. В данном случае будет всегда сохранено последнее значение емейла.

```
$result = [];
foreach($entries as $elem) {
    if(isset($result[$elem['displayname'][0]]) && 
        strpos($elem['email'][0],'yandex.ru') !== false
    ) {
        $result[$elem['displayname'][0]] = $elem['email'][0];
    } else {
        $result[$elem['displayname'][0]] = $elem['email'][0];
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Но неужели в той штуке, в которой Вы храните данные, нет возможности выбрать сразу то, что Вам нужно?

Comment: а где yandex.ru ? :) смысл не просто всегда выбрать контакт (это я могу через фильтр), а если будут два одинаковых с ключами displayname, то взять email с яндексом.

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko, вот.